# unable to open file 'config1.cfg' (benchmarks)

Tags: ros, moveit, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been following the tutorial on benchmarking according to this [link](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Benchmarking).
I was able to make a configuration file (I names it config1.cfg like in the tutorial) after I added some scenes and queries to my database.

```
[scene]
name=No_obstacles_1
runs=2
timeout = 10
output = mylocation.log


[plugin]
name=ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
planners=RRTConnectkConfigDefault PRMkConfigDefault
runs = 10
```

When I try to run the benchmark I use the following command:

```
roslaunch epson_moveit_generated run_benchmark_ompl.launch cfg:=config1.cfg
```

But it fails at a certain point:

```
[ INFO] [1398856673.630905167]: Loading robot model 'epsonURDF_gripper'...
[ INFO] [1398856674.403549421]: Loading robot model 'epsonURDF_gripper'...
[ INFO] [1398856676.779398433]: Attempting to load and configure ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[ INFO] [1398856676.872126099]: Initializing OMPL interface using ROS parameters
[ INFO] [1398856676.914059532]: Available planner instances: ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner 
[ INFO] [1398856676.914178469]: Loading 'config1.cfg'...
[ERROR] [1398856676.914321241]: Unable to open file 'config1.cfg'
[ INFO] [1398856676.914449454]: Processed 0 benchmark configuration files
[ INFO] [1398856676.940193257]: Benchmarks complete! Shutting down ROS...
[moveit_benchmark_padplanningyaj_CELSIUS_H700_21444_1771399437-2] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/padplanningyaj/.ros/log/db564e20-d03b-11e3-8134-58946b4707fc/moveit_benchmark_padplanningyaj_CELSIUS_H700_21444_1771399437-2*.log
```

So it's unable to open or even find the config file. Can someone explain me why this error occurs and how I can solve it?

---

I am running ROS hydro in ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/159041/unable-to-open-file-%27config1.cfg%27-(benchmarks)/) by [Yannik_K](https://answers.ros.org/users/9556/yannik_k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2014-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When nodes are launched through roslaunch, their current working directory is set to ROS_HOME ( usually ~/.ros ).

This means that any file names you provide should use the full path to the file instead of a relative path. I would retry your launch with the full path to your config file.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1